# Decoding an object when original class is unavailable and class is unknown

Tags: ios, swift, nscoding, nskeyedarchiver

This is very similar to this question: [How can I decode an object when original class is not available?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25492158/482536), but what's the best way to do this if the data I am unarchiving could be any class conforming to a certain protocol?

As a simple example,

```swift
protocol TestProtocol: NSCoding { }

class A: TestProtocol { }
class B: TestProtocol { }
class C: TestProtocol { }
// And 20 more classes
...

let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "TestKey") as! Data
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(<SomeClassConformingToTestProtocol?>, forClassName: String(describing: <SomeClassConformingToTestProtocol>)) // No class to pass in here, but protocol is known.
NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as! TestProtocol
```

I could loop through every class and call

```swift
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(A.self, forClassName: "A")
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(B.self, forClassName: "B")
NSKeyedUnarchiver.setClass(C.self, forClassName: "C")
```

But that means whenever there is a new class in `TestProtocol`, it needs to be added to this list and seems unenforceable.

I've tried overriding `classFallbacksForKeyedArchiver()` to provide a fallback class name if the original class is not found, but this is still throwing an `NSInvalidUnarchiveOperationException` when unarchiving in my project's Share Extension.

Is there a better way to do this other than to remembering to add classes to an array when a new class (conforming to a protocol) is created?

Comment: How do you encode the object? If you know the class you use for encoding, then you should be able to use it for decoding.

Comment: @Cristik Good question, I don't know the class for encoding either, so I'm also looping through each class and calling `NSKeyedArchiver.setClassName("A", for: A.self) ...` too.

Comment: Who's doing the encoding? You or someone else? Do you have control over the encoding code?

Comment: Yes I am doing the encoding, and yes I do have control over the encoding code. The  `TestProtocol` also conforms to `NSCoding`

Comment: You can't encode protocols, though, you need a concrete class for that. Your `TestProtocol` actually is inheriting `NSCopying` instead of conforming to it.

Comment: Sorry I meant `TestProtocol` inherits `NSCoding` instead of conforming to it. The classes that conform to `TestProtocol` conform to `NSCoding` as well.

Comment: Also, if you have control over the encoding code, you can also store the class name used for encoding and use `NSClassFromName` on the decoding side.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200412/discussion-between-cody-and-cristik).